# highcharts with Angular get http value to typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I want to get http value to the typescript use it.
my js code

```
[{"ID":"1","hee":"S1","thid":"wqriehjfeoghetiogjetlgj","thinfo":"hello"},{"ID":"2","hee":"S2","thid":"moiiooofgijtigjw","thinfo":"hiiii"}]
```

my highcharts code

```
@Component({ 
 selector: 'app-basic-column', 
 templateUrl: './basic-column.component.html', 
 styleUrls: ['./basic-column.component.scss'] 
}) 
export class BasicColumnComponent implements OnInit { 

 Idata=[];
 
 chartOptions = {}; 
 
 Highcharts = Highcharts; 
 
 @Input() data = []; 
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.http.get('http://localhost/php/test.php').subscribe(Idata => {
    this.Idata.push(Idata);
    console.log(this.Idata);
    }, error => console.error(error));
}
 ngOnInit(): void { 
  this.chartOptions = { 
    chart: { 
        type: 'bar' 
     }, 
    title: { 
        text: this.Idata  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I want to change it.
    }, 
 subtitle: { 
        text: 'Source: HP Security Validation Lab' 
 }
}
```

The tittle I want to change the data but output are [object object],[object object]
My PHP code is SQL code.
The data change to PHP data.
the typescript need to modify? or my php code need to modify?

Comment: When you say that the output is [object object],[object object]  you mean that that's what console.log outputs ? Another question would be, what is the type of Idata that the subscription returns ?

Comment: thanks for your reply.[object object],[object object] is title this.Idata << output , how to check Idata that the the subscription returns?

Comment: You can do `console.log(Idata)` inside the subscription anonymous function body. With your `console.log(this.Idata);` you log the Idata field of your component. It might be a good idea to change one of the Idata variable names to avoid confusion.

Comment: console.log(Idata) are array. how to check feedback

Comment: I do not know what you mean by feedback. If you want to set the highcharts title from Idata just traverse the object you acquired through the subscription to get the data you want.

Comment: but I can't to get value....when I use this.Idata[1]

Comment: I do not know what this.Idata outputs. You said that Idata is an array. So when you do `this.Idata.push(Idata); ` I imagine that you push an array into another array. I cannot answer if there is something wrong with the object that you receive in the subscription or if you handle it wrong. Giving me more info about the object type that you receive would help me (and you) more. 
Given that you write in typescript, object types should be used whenever possible.